# Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986 when uploading file

Tags: java, tomcat

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:467)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:294)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

When uploading to a web service running on Tomcat 9.0.2 that error is thrown, I already added `tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.requestTargetAllow=|{}` on *catalina.properties*

Comment: Is it a direct `GET` request from a browser? or forwarded from another servlet?

Comment: Direct POST from the browser